# Monitor Processes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, operating-system

I have the below code. the problem that lies is that i need to define the variables(mesa condition) and functions so that only at most 8 processes can communicate (1 at a time).

```
SesMoni M;

int main() {
...
M.LockoutAccess():

M.FreeAccess():
....
}

Monitor SensorMonitor {
/* Variables???????? */

void LockoutAccess() { /*????????/* }
void freeAccess() { /*????????/* }
```

so far i have got the base code(below but it is only for allocating a single resouce. How can i achieve this to allow at most 8 resources placing this in the above code?

```
{
boolean busy;
condition x;

void acquire(int time) {
  if (busy)
    x.wait(time);
}

void release() {
    busy = false;
    x.signal()
}
initialization.code()  {
    busy = false;
    }
}
```

An external sensor is connected to a computer by a serial line. Only one process at a time can communicate with the sensor. The controller of the serial line can maintain access to the sensor from at most 7 processes.
In pseudo-code write a monitor to coordinate process access to the external sensor.

The monitor pseudo-code needs to deﬁne monitor variables and the monitor functions so that at most only 7 processes are actually communicating with the sensor.

Comment: What language are you using?  The second fragment isn't C code, as far as I can see — it's similar, but not orthodox C (but then again, it might be Linux Kernel C, which might not be wholly orthodox either).  The first fragment is missing a `}`; it might or might not be C depending on where that goes.  There is a lot of information missing (or I don't know enough about what you're doing/asking to understand what you're up to).

Comment: hi the code is in c, im really trying to check the logic and create so at most 8 processes are used for the monitor

Comment: The outer braces around the second block of code are … odd.  I suggest removing them; it would leave your code nearly kosher.  The notation `initialization.code() { … }` is still not orthodox C; you can't have a dot in a function name.  The notation `Monitor SensorMonitor { …` in the first fragment is likewise not recognizable as C code, though it could be made valid with a suitable macro definition for `SensorMonitor`.  If you're writing pseudo-code, I suggest making that clearer.  I'm not clear what you mean by 'mesa condition'.

Comment: It really isn't clear to me the context of the question.  I recommend temporarily deleting the question, editing it to clarify what you're asking, and then undeleting the question.

Comment: I've seen what the update is.  I'm none the wiser after it.  Sorry, I can't help.